# How to check if a file that contains the ┤character in its name exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I have a file named `a┤rv.txt` on Windows, I'd like to know if this file exists.

I've tried to use the following but it always returns `Unsupported characters in input`:

```python
>>> import os

>>> os.path.isfile("C:\Users\Zignd\Desktop\test\a┤rv.txt")
```

I think I need to encode this string in some standard. I tried UTF-8, but it returns the same message.

```python
>>> import os

>>> os.path.isfile("C:\Users\Zignd\Desktop\test\a┤rv.txt".encode('utf-8'))
```

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to implement the idea above to list the files in a directory, so here is the full function definition:

```python
def imprimir(path):
    path = path.encode('utf8')
    print path
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for i in range(len(files)):
        sub = os.path.join(path, files[i])
        if os.path.isfile(sub):
            print sub
```

Comment: You'd *decode* a byte string to unicode. Are you certain your console is configured to handle UTF-8?

Comment: When I try your code on Windows 7 with Python 2.6, it is returning False. Not very helpful, but a little different than what you're receiving.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using IDLE with Python 2.7.6 on Windows 8 (EN-US) so I went to "Configure IDLE..." and checked the UTF-8 option then I applied the configurations and to make sure, I closed IDLE and opened it again, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Did you try using a `unicode` literal for the filename?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The same error returns, when I use: `os.path.isfile(u"C:\Users\Zignd\Desktop\test\a┤rv.txt")`

Comment: Oh, wait. Try escaping your backslashes.

Comment: Janky idea, but try to [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) it and then check the filename's literal string?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That don't work too.

Comment: I wiil edit the question and add the function I defined and is not working.

Comment: Are you sure it's really `┤` (from the OEM code page) and not `´` (the corresponding character from the ANSI code page)?

Comment: @dan04 well, it's this character http://unicode-table.com/en/2524/

Answer (score 0):

With Python 2.7 on Windows 7, if I do an os.listdir on the folder that contains a file with the name "a┤rv.txt", it doesn't show up in the returned list.

However, if I make the folder path into a unicode string and do an os.listdir, I get the following name back:

```
d = u'C:\\Users\\mdriscoll\\Desktop'
os.listdir(d) # returns u'a\u2524rv.txt' along with a list of other files

f = u'a\u2524rv.txt'
path = os.path.join(d, f)
print os.path.isfile(path) # returns True
```

This works for 2.7, although I can't think of a way you can use it.

Comment: Can't test on Windows to see if this works so I won't make this an answer myself, but, would [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) work?

Comment: I tried glob and it returns a version of the filename, but when you do os.path.isfile, it still returns False

Comment: Yeah I tried with Python 3.x too, and it worked, the problem is that I really needs to use Python 2.7.x

Comment: `\Uhhhhhhhh` is a unicode escape sequence for wide characters; `\Users` looks like such an escape sequence gone wrong. Double the backslashes or uses forward slashes.

Comment: And when using bytecode path values on Windows, you'd need to use the UTF-16 codec as that is the filesystem codec used on that OS.

Comment: When doing a fname = u'a┤rv.txt'.encode("utf16"), I get the "unsupported characters" message